# Updated UWP package doesn't show up on Microsoft Store

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, msix

I'm trying to update my UWP app on store. But for some reason, even days after publishing the updated package, the app is not updated. The listing details on store are updated though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated UWP package doesn't show up on Microsoft Store

For your problem, the better way is that connect store team. they could check your app's state.

We suggest you open a free support ticket here: [Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/). Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic, and select App submissions and management for issue type.